# Check String whether it contains certain charecters Java Regular Expression

Tags: java, regex

I want to check a string true or false under these conditions:

```
1. the string must be 5 charecters long
2. 3rd charecter should be 'b'
3. the string must contain special charecter like '?' or '@' and '$'
```

I can't figure what to do still I've done:

```
System.out.println("//b//b//b?//b//b//b" ,"akb?g");//this is totally wrong though
```

Comment: What is your ``//b`` supposed to mean?

Comment: One of your strings isn't closed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try using this pattern:

```
^(?=.*[?@$]).{2}b.{2}$
```

Here is a code snippet showing how you might use this pattern:

```
if ("invalid".matches("(?=.*[?@$]).{2}b.{2}")) {
    System.out.println("invalid matches");
}
if ("12b?3".matches("(?=.*[?@$]).{2}b.{2}")) {
    System.out.println("12b?3 matches");
}
```

### Demo

Here is a brief explanation of the pattern:

```
^            from the start of the string
(?=.*[?@$])  assert that we see a special character anywhere, at least once
.{2}         then match any two characters
b            match a 'b' for the 3rd character
.{2}         then match any two characters again
$            end of string
```

Comment: Would you please little explain that would be really helpful. Appriciate your effort. thank you

Answer (score 4):

If you meant '?' or ('@' and '$') use this

```
(
   (?=.*[\$?])      // Must contain either $ or ?
   (?=.*[@?])       // Must contain either @ or ?
    ..b..$          // Third character should be b
)
```

One line

```
((?=.*[\$?])(?=.*[@?])..b..$)
```